# Does Google Groups have its own Google product forum?

Tags: google-groups, google-product-forums

Google has forums for many of its products (see [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!home;lang=en)).  But I don't see Google Groups there.  Is there an official Google forum for Google Groups?

Answer (score 1):

That *is* odd, considering they use Google Groups to power their Product Forums.

If you go to "Help and Feedback" within Google Groups, there's an option at the bottom of the menu that comes up that says "[Visit Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?authuser=0#!categories/apps/google-groups-for-business)".

That link brings you to the [G Suite Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/apps/category$3Agoogle-groups-for-business%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) filtered by the "Google Groups" category.

There doesn't seem to be anywhere else. Certainly I'm not seeing a forum dedicated to the "normal" consumer version of Groups.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I guess I'll try posting to the umbrella G Suite Help Forum.  
**That is odd, considering they use Google Groups to power their Product Forums.**

Yep.  It also makes it difficult to search for help on Google Groups.